# How can I count the number of faces in $K_2$?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I studied that in $K_2$ we have $V=2$, $E=1$, and $F=1$, and in $K_3$, we have $V=3$, $E=3$, and $F=2.$

But where is the face in $K_2$? There is only one line in there.

Comment: The outside of the graph is also counted as a face - for example $K_3$ has 2 faces.

Comment: But where is the outside of K2 and inside of K2 ?

Comment: $K_2$ has only one face, as you say, which is just the plane without the graph

Comment: By definition, a face of a plane graph $K$ is a connected component of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K$

Answer (score 1):

As [ArtW](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/191773/artw) says in the comments, you can define the *faces* of a planar embedding of a graph $G$ to be the connected components of the plane minus the graph ($\mathbb{R}^2-G$). Since any embedding of $K_2$ in the plane is just a line, there is a single connected component, so $K_2$ has one face.